# rotate and zoom 3d object in Aframe

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I'm testing very basic 3D object viewer using A-frame , I'm unable to rotate and move around the 3D object " .gltf " I looked to multiple examples and all seems to be really not good .

```html
  

  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
      <script src=" https://unpkg.com/aframe-orbit-controls@1.3.0/dist/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <a-scene>


      <a-gltf-model src="UntitledScene.gltf" position="0 0 0" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1.5 1.5 1.5" size="20px"></a-gltf-model>
      

    </a-scene>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Do you know what is the best setting to achieve an acceptable 3D control ?
I'm viewing using IPAD/Iphone  .
My ideal control is similar to sketch fab model viewer .

Comment: try using model-viewer by google. It helps you to create your own viewer

Comment: This actually answered my question ! I dont think I even needed to use A-Frame , three.js is enough but complicated while Model-viewer is much simpler . Thanks,

Comment: Thank you for recognizing and appreciating

Answer (score 0):

@ajai.s recommended Model-viewer by google , which provided exactly the answer I'm looking for .
for my use case I didnt even needed A-frame .